# Using Streams and filter in Java and matching with a varargs

Tags: java, java-stream, variadic-functions

I know that `.contains` needs a string. Varargs can be a String structure of more than one. Like `String... role` can be `"user", "admin"`. Or `String... role` can be `"user"`.

Whatever is passed into it will be used.

So I have a filter - where I am trying to see if the getter thats a type String contains the value found in the varargs...

```
 String a = Arrays.toString(role);
 System.out.print(a);
 TypeOfObject roles = userProjectRoles.stream().filter(userProjectRole ->
    userProjectRole.getRole().getName().equals(a)).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

a has brackets and it is not a string, but an Array sent as a string value.

Can you help me on how to fix this?

Comment: Is your goal - find all the roles from `userProjectRoles` that match *any* in `role` array?

Comment: Yes. My goal is to check if the getter..... userProjectRole.getRole().getName() < getName is a string has a value in it like 'user' contains - any  of whatever is passed in the varargs.

Answer (score 1):

Convert input array to Set and use its `contains()` method

```
 Set<String> roleSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(role));
 TypeOfObject roles = userProjectRoles.stream()
     .filter(userProjectRole -> roleSet.contains(userProjectRole.getRole().getName())
     .findFirst()
     .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter `userProjectRoles` with the anyMatch method to check if `roles` contains that role:

```
var result = userProjectRoles.stream()
  .map(role -> role.getRole().getName())
  .filter(roleName -> Arrays.stream(roles).anyMatch(role -> roleName.equals(role)))
  .collect(Collectors.toList())

or

var result = userProjectRoles.stream()
  .map(role -> role.getRole().getName())
  .filter(roleName -> {
    for (String role : roles) if (roleName.equals(role)) return true;
    return false;
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This will give you all of the elements in `userProjectRoles` whose names are also in the `roles` array, if I understand your question correctly.

If it's the other way around and you want all the elements in the `roles` array that are also in `userProjectRoles`, you can do this:

```
List<String> roleNames = 
  roles.stream()
    .map(role -> role.getRole().getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
var result = Arrays.stream(roles).stream()
  .filter(roleNames::contains)
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: This will create a new stream from `role` for every element in `userProjectRoles` - not very efficient

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky I'll use a for loop then

Answer (score -1):

I presume you're trying to get rid of [ and ] from Arrays#toString but it's unclear since there is no direct answer. If so, this is how.

It is worth noting that this is unsafe because the result of role could be multiple values and not a single one.

```java
String a = Arrays.toString(role).replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("]", "");
```

An alternative might be to check if the array of roles contains the role name. I.e;

```java
TypeOfObject roles = userProjectRoles.stream()
    .filter(userProjectRole -> Stream.of(a).anyMatch(roleName -> userProjectRole.getRole().getName().equals(roleName))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Either or trying to check if an varags is equal to the string getter. 

I think it is the filtering thats throwing me a loop.

Comment: Well remember that varargs is just a String array. You cannot compare a String array to a String. When filtering what you're doing is checking if the `userProjectRoles` as a Stream of individual role objects exists in a Stream of roles `a` by checking if any of the individual String objects in the `a` array contains `userProjectRole.getRole().getName()`

Comment: I think what OP is actually trying to achieve is to check whether the `array` contains one of the roles of the user. So this whole converting the vararg array to a single string seems like the completely wrong approach, he should probably convert it to a List and check in the filter whether `roleName` is contained inside that List.

Comment: Yes! That is correct! I didn't think about that! So should be a .contains not a .equals

Comment: No. A is not an object (per say). It is of the type `Array` which does not have a `contains` method.

Comment: Yes that is correct too. I tried using Arrays.asList() as my first option and its not valid.

Comment: the RoleName comes up - as not knowing what it is - can you tell me what you mean by RoleName after the anyMatch()? I assume anyMatch matches anything found in the getter.

Comment: Sorry but this discussion is beyond the context of the question. You're going to have to ask another question with clearer description.